# SSIS C# Script CSV Destination with variable column length output

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a project where I was asked to combine a lot individual packages into a unified project. 
Essentially all packages are exporting data from the database to CSV files. I am trying to make it so that I have one package that loads the individual jobs and can execute each.

I have 3 variables for the process.

- Column Delimiter
- Column length
- File Output Path

I have a process that formats the data so that I am always receiving 100 columns of varchar(4000) data. to please SSIS.

I am by no means a c# person. So here is where I need the help. I want the C# script destination to read an input variable to know the column length, Then loop each column creating the output statement.

I have the below code:

I want to generate the output statement in the `PreExecute` then execute it durring `Input0_ProcessInputRow`

Is this possible?

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    private string OutputFile;
    private int ColumnCount;
    private string ColumnDelimiter;
    private string DefaultColumnDelimiter = ",";
    private StreamWriter textWriter;
    private string DynamicEXEString;

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        // CREATE THE SET UP FOR THE CSV FILE AND THE OUTPUT
        ColumnCount = Variables.CC; 
        OutputFile = Variables.OP; 
        ColumnDelimiter = Variables.DL; 

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ColumnDelimiter))
        {
            ColumnDelimiter = DefaultColumnDelimiter;
        }

        textWriter = new StreamWriter(OutputFile, false);
        for (int i = 1; i <= ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            DynamicEXEString += String.Format("textWriter.Write(Row.Column{0});" + Environment.NewLine, i);
            if (i != ColumnCount) // OUTPUT DELIMITER FOR ALL BUT THE LAST ROW. INSTEAD WRITE THE LINE.
            {
                DynamicEXEString += "textWriter.Write(columnDelimiter);" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                DynamicEXEString += "textWriter.WriteLine();";
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(DynamicEXEString); //DEBUG ONLY OUTPUT WHAT THE VALUES ARE.
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        /*
         * EXECUTE THE CODE THAT IS STORED IN THE VARIABLE DynamicEXEString
         */
    }

}
```